# Eclipse RCP Eclipse Application Run error --

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp

I got this error trying to run an Eclipse Application on Eclipse version 3.8.2:

An error has occurred. See the log file

> PATHTO
>   PROJECT/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/PRODUCT_FOLDER/1444675727934.log

But there is  no log file.  There is no compilation errors.

What is going on and how can I get a better error message?

Thanks much,
Springgrass

Comment: Have you looked for a file named 1444675727934.log anywhere on your file system?

Comment: Yes, there is no such file anywhere

Comment: Try adding `-consoleLog -debug` to the Program Arguments in the Run Configuration for the application, this may give you more information in the console view when you start the app.

Comment: Thanks... I figured out that I didn't add some required feature to the feature.xml, and that's why it doesn't work... the errors didn't help :-)